# How can I regain my SSD Icon in the launcher?

Tags: unity, mount, launcher

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux and as a matter of fact I just loaded Ubuntu onto my system! I own an Asus G75VW-DS72 and I upgraded my C drive to a Samsung Evo 1TB that has windows on it and I've loaded the Ubuntu files on my Samsung Pro 512GB on the D drive.  When I was trying out Ubuntu I had the two disk drive icons on the launchpad.  Now that I've loaded Ubuntu on the D drive I've lost the D drive icon.  My file system icon still appears to have my Ubuntu files on it.

Is it even a problem if I do not have this icon?  How can I get this icon back?

I'm sorry is this is a true newbie question, I am not familiar with linux and this is a learning experience.

I ran sudo fdisk -l and it indicates the following:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121126 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5209c5df

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1000215215   500107607+  ee  GPT
```

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

- If you're using Ubuntu with Unity, that thing on the left edge of the screen is the launcher.
- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/) is a web site where Ubuntu development takes place.
- `fdisk` only works properly with MBR/MS-DOS partition tables. If you have GPT partition tables, use `gdisk` or better `parted`. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.
- Linux doesn't use drive letters.

**To answer your question:**

Yes it's normal that the drive or partition where the Ubuntu root filesystem resides is not shown in the launcher as a removable disk drive or physical drive. Use Nautilus (the "Files" application) to browse your computer and files.

Yes you are right, "filesystem" in Nautilus is the drive where Ubuntu is installed on. When filesystems are mounted via the `/etc/fstab` file they will not show up (with some exceptions like the `/media` location) as a icon in the launcher or physical drive in Nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for your help LiveWireBT and thanks for the info regarding the terminology!